# How do I repeat the action on a block until a specific simulation time has occured?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

So I am wondering how I can repeat a action a block until the model simulation time has reached 30 minutes. to elaborate further:

I have this flow right now:

PedSource -> PedWait1 -> PedGoTo -> PedWait2 - PedGoTo2

So for PedWait2 the agents(which are nurses) are going to check upon different patients by going to their rooms (different attractors). So what I want is to repeat that the nurses check on the patients until the time of the simulation reaches 30 minutes and then enter PedGoTo2. So basically, While the time is under 30 minutes, keep checking on patients and when time is 30 minutes PedGoTo2.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SelectOutput` element after `PedWait2`.

Switch it to "condition-based" and connect its "true" exit to `PedGoto2`. Connect its "false" exit back to the entry of `PedWait1`.

In the condition, use `time(MINUTE)>=30` and you are good to go.